# How to get a list of packages I installed?

Tags: apt, system-installation, software-installation, package-management, kubuntu

I have a Kubuntu 14.10 install that I am considering backing up and recreating as I've been upgrading it since 12.04 and I'm having a few issues that might be due to age. Since I've been using it for years, I have a lot of data and programs installed.

I can easily back up the data and my PPAs but I want to cleanly reinstall programs I have installed and am looking for a way to get a list of them. I have browsed /var/log/apt/history.log but it only seems to go back about a year (and has a lot of extraneous stuff).

Basically what I am looking for is a list of packages that I installed via "apt-get install" that does not include any dependencies (which would be installed automatically) nor anything that comes already in Kubuntu (which naturally is already there) so that on a clean install I could just run "apt-get install x y z . . . . ." with everything I need.

Does such a list exist?

EDIT: I don't believe this is a duplicate as what I am looking for are only packages that I installed myself (no dependencies nor packages that come with Kubuntu).

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate. The linked question asks how to get a list of **all** installed packages on the system. This question asks how to get a list of packages that only includes those that the user manually installed using `apt-get install` with dependencies filtered out.

Comment: [This question on Unix & Linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288024/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-packages-that-i-have-installed-using-apt-get) is more closely related to this question. It doesn't specifically ask for dependencies to be filtered out, but it seems that that is what the OP on that question would desire anyway, so it's probably a suitable duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
  dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

Source: 
[How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I found that too but it gives every package installed in the system. What I am looking for are only packages that I have installed myself (no dependencies or packages that come with Kubuntu). If that is not possible then this looks to be the closest I can get.

Comment: This: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?31231-FAQ-How-to-get-list-of-installed-packages has an aptitude command to list the manually installed packages.