# Write a script to automate installing applications on freshly installed Ubuntu

Tags: scripts

Do not ask me why, but I often found myself installing a Linux distribution (e.g. Ubuntu) over and over again in a year time. For myself or others.

I often found myself installing the same application to get my system up and running. Since only one installing process can acces my system at a time, I have to wait for one installation to finish in my terminal for me to install a new program in the terminal.

```
user@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install [application]
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

This is inefficient since I have to keep an eye on my terminal and wait for it to finish. That's the reason I wonder:

**1. Can you create a queue in the terminal so that after one installation finishes it will continue to the next?**

**2. Can you write a script to do this? How would it look like?**

My last question which, is kind of a longshot, is there a way that you can see what is installed and automatically add this to a script or something. All of this is part of my soft-backup plan. If I ruin my system and corrupt my files, I can always return to stock ubuntu in under an hour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. Can you create a queue in the terminal so that after one installation finishes it will continue to the next?

Yes. You can add packages like this:

```
  sudo apt-get install sm-player vlc chromium
```

> 2. Can you write a script to do this? How would it look like?

Yes. Just put above mentioned one-liner into a text file and make it executable with `chmod 664 textfile`. You can then do `./textfile` and it will start installing. It might be smart to add a `--yes` in the command otherwise it will prompt for confirmation.

You can add a lot more to such a script. You can even add `gsettings`. See [How do I make post-install scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47404/how-do-i-make-post-install-scripts) for an example.

> My last question which, is kind of a longshot, is there a way that you can see what is installed and automatically add this to a script or something.

Yes. See:

- [Write List of Packages installed via Manual Invocation of apt-get to File](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378650/write-list-of-packages-installed-via-manual-invocation-of-apt-get-to-file)
- [How to get a list of packages I installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543222/how-to-get-a-list-of-packages-i-installed)
- [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)